# Read HashMap<String, HashMap<Double, Integer>

Tags: java, hashmap

There is a `HashMap`:

```
HashMap aircraftHandling = new HashMap<String, HashMap<Double, Integer>>();
```

This `HashMap` contains the following entries:

```
HashMap<"M", HashMap<1.22, 200>>();
HashMap<"M", HashMap<5.62, 300>>();
HashMap<"L", HashMap<10.11, 900>>();
```

I need to get entries for the key "M", i.e. `HashMap<1.22, 200>` and `HashMap<5.62, 300>`. I do this in the following way:

```
HashMap lines = (HashMap<Double, Integer>) aircraftHandling.get("M");
```

The question is how to get `Double` and `Integer`, ie (1.22, 200) and (5.62, 300), into two separate variables?

```
for (int i=0; i<lines.size(); i++)
{
  //doubleValue = [i]???
  //integerValue = [i]???
}
```

Comment: You can't have two entries with the same key. The first will be overwrite.

Comment: @GMZ I believe that entries are inside map that is stored under "M" key.

Comment: In this example with one HashMap named **aircraftHandling** and three entries it will have only 2 entries because the first (HashMap<"M", HashMap<1.22, 200>>();) will be override by the second (HashMap<"M", HashMap<5.62, 300>>();). That's how I understud this question.

Comment: @GMZ You might be right, but there is also small chance that OP is using something like http://pastebin.com/mb53kYLx but he didn't described it correctly in his question. Anyway you are right about part that under one key there can be only one value.

Comment: The code you posted implies that your inner map will be better represented by it's own class instead of a key/value pair

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you would extract a **key-value pair** of the `HashMap` by iterating over a *keyset*:

```
Iterator<Double> it= lines.keySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Double key= it.next();
    Integer value= lines.get(key);
}
```

---

On the side note, I don't know if this is an error, or just a bad representation of your data:

```
HashMap<"M", HashMap<1.22, 200>>();
HashMap<"M", HashMap<5.62, 300>>();
```

But if it is how it looks, this is impossible. A `Map` can have a single value for a single key! That means, if you put some value for a key `"M"` and you do it again for the same key, the latter will overwrite the previous value. What you should do is:

```
//get the inner map for "M"
HashMap<Double, Integer> innerMap= aircraftHandling.get("M");
if (innerMap == null) {
    //if it does not exist instantiate it
    innerMap= new HashMap<Double, Integer>();
    aircraftHandling.put("M", innerMap);
}
```

and now, in the `innerMap` you add other values, e.g.:

```
innerMap.put(1.22, 200);
innerMap.put(5.62, 300);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use an enhanced for loop just to read elements :

```
for (Map.Entry<Double, Integer> entry : lines.entrySet()) {
   Double key = entry.getKey();
   Integer value = entry.getValue();
}
```

---

*This HashMap contains the following entries:*

```
HashMap<"M", HashMap<1.22, 200>>();
HashMap<"M", HashMap<5.62, 300>>();
HashMap<"L", HashMap<10.11, 900>>();
```

*I need to get entries for the key "M", i.e. HashMap<1.22, 200> and HashMap<5.62, 300>. I do this in the following way:*

Not considering the syntax used , since the key is a `String` , the second time you try to `put()` a value in the `Map` using a `String` key which already exists in `Map` **the new value will override the old value.**

Answer (score 2):

Try maybe this way

```
Map<Double, Integer> lines = (HashMap<Double, Integer>) aircraftHandling.get("M");
// ^add this generic types here so you wont have to cast them later with getters
for (Map.Entry<Double, Integer> entry:lines.entrySet()){
    Double key = entry.getKey();
    Integer value = entry.getValue();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you have it:

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<Double, Integer>> aircraftHandling = new HashMap<String,    HashMap<Double, Integer>>();

HashMap<Double, Integer> subMap1 = new HashMap<Double, Integer>();
subMap1.put(1.22, 200);

HashMap<Double, Integer> subMap2 = new HashMap<Double, Integer>();
subMap1.put(5.62, 300);

aircraftHandling.put("M", subMap1);
aircraftHandling.put("L", subMap2);

HashMap<Double, Integer> lines = aircraftHandling.get("M");

for (Entry<Double, Integer> set : lines.entrySet()) {
    Double doubleValue = set.getKey();
    Integer integerValue = set.getValue();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, Map can't have duplicate key. If you insert duplicate key then previous one will disappear. You can use following code to separate key and value:

```
     HashMap lines = (HashMap<Double, Integer>) aircraftHandling.get("M");

     for(Map.Entry<Double, Integer> entry: lines ){

        doubleValue = entry.getKey();
        integerValue =entry.getValue();
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

with a foreach loop and method `HashMap.entrySet()` :

```
HashMap<Double, Integer> map=...
for(Entry<Double,Integer> entry : map.entrySet()){
   Double d = entry.getKey();
   Integer i = entry.getValue();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have 2 values for the key M. I hope you've taken care of that while putting the values. You should have put one hashmap for the value M.

You simply need to fetch the hashmap corresponding to key M

```
HashMap lines = (HashMap<Double, Integer>) aircraftHandling.get("M");
```

And then iterate over all entries in this map

```
Iterator it = lines.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
    double d = pairs.getKey().doubleValue();
    int i = pairs.getValue().intValue();
}
```

EDIT - Had answered from my mobile so missed a few details. Adding them now.